# connecting to native client 11 on VBA

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, connection-string

I have some vba code that is working fine but I now have to run this code with data from a different database. The new database driver is SQL Server Native Client 11. I suspect something is wrong with the connection string because it is a different driver. Can this code be used if I just replace the "provider=" to {SQL Server Native Client 11.0} or does it require all new variables to be declare, etc...

```
Private Sub sqlQueryScript()
On Error GoTo CleanUp

'Declare variables'
    Dim user As String
    Dim conn As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim strSql As String
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    
'Open receipt connection'
    user = Environ("username")
    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
        "Data Source=C:\Users\" & user & "\Desktop\db\" & dbName
    conn.Open
    
'Set and Excecute SQL Command'
    strSql = query

'Open Recordset'
    Set rs = conn.Execute(strSql)
    rs.Close
    rs.Open strSql
    
'Copy Data to Excel'
    Set data = Workbooks(fName).Sheets(fac)
    data.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
    
'Copy Header to Excel
    For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        data.Cells(1, i + 1).Value = rs.Fields(i).Name
    Next i
CleanUp:
'Close Connection'
    conn.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following connection string for a connection with Windows Authentication:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Data Source=ServerName
```

Answer (score 1):

The connection string for SQL Server Native Client 11 Ole db provider is something like:

```
Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Data Source=ServerName\InstanceName
```

If the SQL Server instance is the default instance, then use only the server name, `Data Source=ServerName`

You don't need to change anything more. Perhaps you need to change the query to be compatible with SQL Server.